# Error if I specify MetadataDirective while calling put_object on s3 python SDK

Tags: amazon-s3

Here is my code:

```
import boto3


BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket'
FILE_NAME = 'three-puppies.jpg'

data = open(FILE_NAME, 'rb')

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

metadata = {
    'Content-Type' : 'image/jpeg'
}

s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put_object(Key='new_puppies_file_withmtdt.jpg', Body=data, Metadata=metadata, MetadataDirective="REPLACE")
```

I am expecting that this would change the default metadata when I upload this file. However, when I run this code, I get below error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "MetadataDirective", must be one of: ACL,
```

I expected my file metadata to change from
System defined  Content-Type    binary/octet-stream
to:
User defined    x-amz-meta-content-type image/jpeg

But I see both now:

System defined  Content-Type    binary/octet-stream
User defined    x-amz-meta-content-type image/jpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. `put_object` does not support `MetadataDirective`. Instead we can specify `ContentType` in `put_object`:

```
s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put_object(Key='new_puppies_file.jpg', Body=data, ContentType='image/jpeg')
```